# casting return type with different entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Here is my method and i would like to cast my return - also i am doing this to prevent from changing my different methods i have and wanted to also know will this have any negative affect if a cast my return?

```
public VisitEntry Get(Guid visitEntryId)
    {
        var visitEntry = _visitEntryRepository.Get(visitEntryId);
        VisitEntryDTO dto = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<VisitEntry, VisitEntryDTO>(visitEntry);
        dto.CasePartyIds =
            _casePartyService.GetAllForHearingEntry(visitEntryId).Select(caseParty => caseParty.CasePartyId).ToList();
        return dto;
    }
```

The error i get is for: return dto. Stating: that I cannot converty ...Entity.VisitEntryDTO to ...Entity.VisitEntry.

any clarification will be great. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to cast in the first place?

Comment: because i want to return the results for dto.casePartyIds and i need to use VisitEntryDTO and if i change my method to public VisitEntryDTO... then i will have to change it throughout my code which will be a lot of changes and i was hoping i could find a simple alternative.

Comment: Don't map to the dto in the first place if you just want to return the Entity.  Or if you must, simply map it back again, although that seems sloppy.

Comment: I take it `VisitEntry` *does not* have a `CasePartyIds` property? Which result are you actually trying to acquire from this method? A `VisitEntry` or a list of "case party IDs"?

Comment: @Amina - There is no easy solution. If you want to stick to one datatype you will have to manually populate an object of the return type. Without knowing specifics, I can't comment more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely can't directly cast from `VisitEntryDTO` to `VisitEntry`.  You'll need to Automap back.

However, your repository seemingly already returns `VisitEntry` objects, so why are you mapping to a `VisitEntryDTO` in the first place?  Why not just do:

```
public VisitEntry Get(Guid visitEntryId)
{
    var visitEntry = _visitEntryRepository.Get(visitEntryId);
    visitEntry.CasePartyIds =
        _casePartyService.GetAllForHearingEntry(visitEntryId).Select(caseParty => caseParty.CasePartyId).ToList();
    return visitEntry;
}
```

Unless I'm missing something about your `VisitEntry` class.

Comment: Thank you.. i was over thinking this and wanted to follow the footsteps how i completed this in other places in my code. Thanks for saving me time.